# Regular expression: match word not between quotes

Tags: python, regex, string, quote

I would like a Python regular expression that matches a given word that's not between simple quotes. I've tried to use the `(?! ...)` but without success.

In the following screenshot, I would like to match all `foe` except the one in the 4th line.

Plus, the text is given as one big string.

Here is the link [regex101](https://regex101.com/r/bhQnot/1) and the sample text is below:

```
var foe = 10;
foe = "";
dark_vador = 'bad guy'
foe = ' I\'m your father, foe ! '
bar = thingy + foe
```

Comment: Post your try code

Comment: can you specify the real link to regex101, not screen ?

Comment: Don't post a screenshot - edit in your code.

Comment: It is as easy as matching the single quoted strings (e.g. with `'[^'\\]*(?:\\.[^'\\]*)*'`) and then match *and capture* the word you need. So, the whole would look like `r"'[^'\\]*(?:\\.[^'\\]*)*'|(toto)"`. Then, do whatever you need with the capture (I guess, in a replacement method/lamda expression) in `re.sub`. Since that text looks like some code, this approach will not work well, since comments might contain unbalanced single quotes.

Comment: @Wiktor Stribiżew It's a good start thank you, but if a comment contains a quote the code is messed up afterwards ='(

Comment: So, what are you actually doing? What are you going to do with the matched words?

Comment: I want to replace the matched word with another.

Comment: Is that word always the same, a constant?

Comment: Kind of, I want to do toReplace="foe" and inject it into the regex.

Comment: Sorry, do not use "kind of", what do you want to replace a dynamic value with? Should `foe` be a whole word, not part of? If yes, what is a whole word: string inside whitespaces or within non-word chars?

Comment: I want to replace a variable's name by another in a source code. the replaced name and the name to replace with are given as arguments. Variables can be separated with non-word chars like foe=bar. I already want to use \bfoe\b

Comment: See https://ideone.com/ZkooXP

Comment: @Wiktor Stribiżew Thanks, It works !

Answer (score 5, accepted):

A regex solution below will work in most cases, but it might break if the unbalanced single quotes appear outside of string literals, e.g. in comments.

A usual regex trick to match strings in-context is matching what you need to replace and match and *capture* what you need to keep.

Here is a sample Python demo:

```
import re
rx = r"('[^'\\]*(?:\\.[^'\\]*)*')|\b{0}\b"
s = r"""
    var foe = 10;
    foe = "";
    dark_vador = 'bad guy'
    foe = ' I\'m your father, foe ! '
    bar = thingy + foe"""
toReplace = "foe"
res = re.sub(rx.format(toReplace), lambda m: m.group(1) if m.group(1) else 'NEWORD', s)
print(res)
```

See the [Python demo](https://ideone.com/ZkooXP)

The regex will look like

```
('[^'\\]*(?:\\.[^'\\]*)*')|\bfoe\b
```

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/Qt6tm5/1).

The `('[^'\\]*(?:\\.[^'\\]*)*')` part captures ingle-quoted string literals into Group 1 and if it matches, it is just put back into the result, and `\bfoe\b` matches whole words `foe` in any other string context - and subsequently is replaced with another word.

**NOTE**: To also match double quoted string literals, use `r"('[^'\\]*(?:\\.[^'\\]*)*'|\"[^\"\\]*(?:\\.[^\"\\]*)*\")"`.

Answer (score 3):

You can try this:-

`((?!\'[\w\s]*)foe(?![\w\s]*\'))`

Comment: This matches in `'foe'` in `' I\'m your father, foe ! '`. [ref](https://regex101.com/r/7n2Kll/1/)

Answer (score 2):

How about [this](https://regex101.com/r/csBFdx/3) regular expression:

```
>>> s = '''var foe = 10;
foe = "";
dark_vador = 'bad guy'
' I\m your father, foe ! '
bar = thingy + foe'''
>>>
>>> re.findall(r'(?!\'.*)foe(?!.*\')', s)
['foe', 'foe', 'foe']
```

The trick here is to make sure the expression does not match any string with leading and trailing `'` and to remember to account for the characters in between, thereafter `.*` in the re expression.

Comment: It wouldn't do the trick since the first foe in       foe = ' I\'m your father, foe ! '      needs to be matched ='(

Comment: @Liquiid, you said , it should not match in between single quotes?, so why it should match then?...

Comment: In foe = ' ..... foe....'  it should match only the first one because ii's not in the quotes.

Comment: @Liquiid, your current claim contradicts with your initial requirement. `foe` within `' I\m your father, foe ! '` should not be matched,  otherwise - elaborate your question

Comment: @RomanPerekhrest I want it to watch every foe which aren't between quotes. but  `-->foe<--= ' .... foe ...' ` should be matched

Comment: @Liquiid, Post an example of a string that contains foe and should not match

Comment: @Iron Fist the 4th line of the link I've edited , the second occurrence of foe shouldn't be matched, only the first one.

Answer (score 2):

[image]

```
((?!\'[\w\s]*[\\']*[\w\s]*)foe(?![\w\s]*[\\']*[\w\s]*\'))
```

Comment: It doesn't work if it matches a foe between two quotes. ='(

Comment: @Liquiid: Do not even bother with these answers. Lookarounds won't help you.

Answer (score 0):

Capture group 1 of the following regular expression will contain matches of `'foe'`.

```
r'^(?:[^'\n]|\\')*(?:(?<!\\)'(?:[^'\n]|\\')*(?:(?<!\\)')(?:[^'\n]|\\')*)*\b(foe)\b'
```

[Start your engine!](https://regex101.com/r/7n2Kll/5/)

Python's regex engine performs the following operations.

```
^           : assert beginning of string
(?:         : begin non-capture group
  [^'\n]    : match any char other than single quote and line terminator
  |         : or
  \\'       : match '\' then a single quote
)           : end non-capture group   
*           : execute non-capture group 0+ times
(?:         : begin non-capture group
  (?<!\\)   : next char is not preceded by '\' (negative lookbehind)
  '         : match single quote
  (?:       : begin non-capture group
    [^'\n]  : match any char other than single quote and line terminator
    |       : or
    \\'     : match '\' then a single quote
  )         : end non-capture group   
  *         : execute non-capture group 0+ times
  (?:       : begin non-capture group
    (?<!\\) : next char is not preceded by '\' (negative lookbehind)
    '       : match single quote
  )         : end non-capture group
  (?:       : begin non-capture group
    [^'\n]  : match any char other than single quote and line terminator
    |       : or
    \\'     : match '\' then a single quote
  )         : end non-capture group   
  *         : execute non-capture group 0+ times
)           : end non-capture group
*           : execute non-capture group 0+ times
\b(foe)\b   : match 'foe' in capture group 1
```

Comment: Won't work for " quote obviously and for "foo + '' + bar"