# Regex match comma not inside quotes in rust

Tags: regex, rust

I have a little problem with [this regex crate](https://crates.io/crates/regex) in rust. I need match all ':word' strings, but not inside the quotes.

Unfortunately, some approaches like this `(?!\B"[^"]*)(:[a-zA-Z0-9]{1,})(?![^"]*"\B)`, found [here](https://www.xspdf.com/resolution/50491815.html), doesn't work, returning the `look-around, including look-ahead and look-behind, is not supported` error.

For now, i can match all ':word' strings using this regex: `(:[a-zA-Z0-9]{1,})`

```
let rparams = Regex::new(r#"(:[a-zA-Z0-9]{1,})"#).unwrap(); // doesn't work: match the ':20'

let raw_sql = "select * from aa where a = '10-10-10 20:20'; select * from aa where a = :num";

println!("{}", rparams.replace_all(raw_sql, "?").to_string()); 
// Returns: select * from aa where a = '10-10-10 20?'; select * from aa where a = ?
// Expected: select * from aa where a = '10-10-10 20:20'; select * from aa where a = ?
```

[This code running](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2018&gist=57d93db30fdd7edd738269114c6f036a)

Thanks for any help

Comment: Not Rust, but related: [Regular expression: match word not between quotes](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41137995/regular-expression-match-word-not-between-quotes)

Comment: What's the question? If you have a regex that works, what's the problem? If the regex you have doesn't work, what's wrong with it?

Comment: @trentcl The problem is described in the question: the look-around regex does not work because [`regex`](https://crates.io/crates/regex) doesn't support look-around. He tried another regex, but it matches *everything* instead of only things outside of quotes (see the "Returns" vs "Expected" comments)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Looking at the solution described in [Regular expression: match word not between quotes](https://stackoverflow.com/a/41139792/574531) it seems you can do it without look-arounds by matching the parts you want to replace, while also matching *and capturing* the parts that you want to ignore (text inside quotes).

The necessary regex is simply `('[^']*')|:\w+` -- [regex101 example](https://regex101.com/r/i7MyDc/1)

This will match+capture any pair of single quotes that contain any other characters and match any colon `:` followed by one or more word characters.

You then use a [replacer closure](https://docs.rs/regex/1.3.9/regex/struct.Regex.html#examples-2) with `replace_all` to check the capture groups: if there is a capture group, it will be the matched quote, so replace it with itself; if there is no capture group, it is the matched keyword, so replace it with the desired value.

Example:

```
use regex::{Regex, Captures};

fn main() {
    let rparams = Regex::new(r#"('[^']*')|:\w+"#).unwrap();

    let raw_sql = "select * from aa where a = '10-10-10 20:20'; select * from aa where a = :num";
    println!("{}", rparams.replace_all(raw_sql, |caps: &Captures| {
        match caps.get(1) {
            Some(same) => same.as_str().to_string(),
            None => "?".to_string()
        }
    }).to_string());
}
```

[Playground Link](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2018&gist=734667081dd5b6c5c02a0982f85d15bf)

### Notes:

1. You used `[a-zA-Z0-9]` in your example, but `\w` (which is the same as `[a-zA-Z0-9_]`) seems more reasonable, as it allows for things like `:num_one`
2. This only works if you have balanced quotes in the string
3. This won't work if there are escaped quotes within the quotes (but it could be made to do so with a more complex regex as seen in the linked question)

Comment: Great answer. Small note that in the `regex` crate, `\w` is Unicode aware and is therefore quite a bit larger than `[a-zA-Z0-9_]`. So if you really just want to stick to ASCII, it's best to write it out or use `[[:word:]]` or `(?-u:\w)` which are always ASCII only and always equivalent to `[a-zA-Z0-9_]`.

Answer (score -3):

I think your problem is beyond the capability of a regex.  I think the simplest sound way to approach it is to write a tokenizer to examine all the tokens in the string in order, one at a time.