# Regex to extract characters following 2 forward slashes but ignore if both forward slashes (and following text) are between double quotes

Tags: c#, .net, regex

I am working with some string manipulation where I have a multiline text and have to extract text that follows //, but if // (and text) are between double quotes then match should not happen. A sample of the text I am working with is below:

> This a line // tester 7897
> //Ola
> asdfasdf
> //554654
> Open("asd//Not this")

From the above text I'm expecting the intended Regex to return me the following matches

> // tester 7897
> //Ola
> //554654

I have tried quite a few options but the following regex (with Regex Options Multiline) is the closest I have got to is following one:

> (//).+

This gives me all matches following // and that includes **//Not this** from the last line (which I don't want).

I don't have a lot of experience using Regex. Any help will be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Perhaps you want a negative lookahead and a negative lookbehind? See [here](http://regexstorm.net/reference).

Comment: Are you sure you're capturing the full requirements? What about multiline string literals (`@"..."` in C#)? What about multiline comments (`/* ...*/`)? What about escaped quotes (`"not\"\\this"`)? How perfect does your regex need to be, and how well-defined is the input? If the input is in a parseable language, you may want to use a language parser. If this is just a one-off effort, you might want to just keep things simple and do a little manual correction on the output.

Comment: @Llama, I thought so, but have been stuck with framing an expression that has both of them. A colleague helped me in setting up a negative lookbehind (?<!(".*))//.+
Now trying to figure out how to put in the lookahead

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this.

```
^(?:[^\"\n]|\\\")*(?:(?<!\\)\"(?:[^\"\n]|\\\")*(?:(?<!\\)\")(?:[^\"\n]|\\\")*)*((?:\/\/).*)
```

Here is the link for [regex101](https://regex101.com/r/ZPKAhL/1/).

Here is the [reference](https://stackoverflow.com/a/62627048/578010).

Comment: Thanks for this one. This gives me the matching groups

Answer (score 0):

I do not think this is possible. You want to match everything after `//` only if it is not surrounded by `""`. That would require negative lookaround, and you cannot use negative lookbehind in this case where the number of characters between the first `"` and `//` is not fixed.